# showing complete firebase json data on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase

I'm using firebase to collect data, and i'd like to create a temporary webpage to quickly see the json database (and share it) while testing.
The data is grouped by a date string then the with a random key and then the data. Eg:

```
{
  "20160304" : {
    "-KC-aOwSWpt4dlYmjJE4" : {
      "coordinates" : "-37.7811465912404, 145.005993055861",
      "event" : "Test event",
      "time" : "2016-03-04 07:48:43 +0000"
    }, etc...
```

To test showing the event data I'm using javascript in the html as follows:

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/");

myFirebaseRef.orderByKey().on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("The " + snapshot.key() + " event is " + snapshot.val().event);
  });
});
```

But it only returns
The 20160304 event is undefined
The 20160305 event is undefined

Does anyone know how I can grab the event string?

Comment: Testing? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vulcan-by-firebase/oippbnlmebalopjbkemajgfbglcjhnbl?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to skip a level in your JSON:

```
<date>
    <pushid>
        coordinates: ...
        event: ...
        time: ...
```

Since you're listening on the root if this structure, your `snapshot.forEach()` loops over the dates. That means that you still need to loop over the push ids:

var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/");

```
myFirebaseRef.orderByKey().on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
    var events = snapshot.val();
    Object.keys(events).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(events[key]);
    });
  });
});
```

If on the other hand you only want to cater for one event per day, you should store them without the pushid level in there.

Comment: Do you also know why I get [object Object] and not the detail when I add the line document.write(events[key]);

Comment: Because it's an object; a thing with multiple properties. To see it in its entirety `document.write(JSON.stringify(events[key]))`. But in general: please don't use `document.write()`. Just `console.log()` the same and look at it in your browser's developer tools/JavaScript conosole.

Comment: Thanks frank. Last question if I may, why should I not use `document.write()` in general? Even for testing?